# Non combustible decking options

Tags: decking

We are planning our next project: A rooftop terrace.

We would like to use the full wide of our roof, our city impose non combustible (not A rating) elements withing 1.2m from property limits, so I'm looking for our options and so far I have:

- Aluminium decking
- Porcelain tile
- fiberglass decking
- Plastic wood

is there anything you see I might have forgotten?

Thanks

Comment: Steel is non combustable, square tube framework with thin sheeting for the deck that can be coated so its not slippery or use diamond plate.

Comment: Any idea what the Code requirement is based on? Burning embers from wildfire catching your house on fire?  Firemen needing a stable surface?   Darn shame they don't make walk-on solar panels, you're going to pay a fair bit for a surface, if only you could get one that pays you back!

Comment: I'm downtown Montreal... so for the wildfire I would vote no, I guess it's required to have combustible elements away from your neighbor house to avoid fire propagation. That is why I said property limits which in my case is my neighbor's wall.

Answer (score 2):

Concrete. Does depend on the structure being able to support it. Quite common in commercial roofing, though.

I don't think fiberglass (which is glass fibers in a plastic matrix) nor plastic wood would qualify as **non-combustible.** Both burn quite well, with a horrible stench.

Comment: Depends on the epoxy/etc. used to make the fiberglass.  Actually, a variety of 2-part plastics can be used, Tap Plastics has quite the smorgasboard of FRP-able plastics.

Comment: I didn't put concrete as I don't think my roof will be able to support it.